# Mongoose find() does not return all fields (not enumerable)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

It seems that mongoose.find() ONLY returns the fields (properties) that are defined in your schema; So, if another document in the collection has extra properties, they are not "enumerable" and thus dont 'copy'.  Object.assign() specifying ._doc seems to get all the properties, but maybe I'm missing a better approach.

Comment: What is the question here? I am 100% sure mongoose returns all the data present in db, whether they are in schema or not , could you please elaborate more ?

Comment: In my tests, if the prop isn't in the schema, then mongoose makes it enumerable. Now, if you use ".lean()" on the find() chain it will return the whole JSON object.